# Ambiguous behavior in iterator while using the find/filter methods

Tags: rust

I don’t think I’ve seen this behavior before while using iterators. I have the following program.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::<String, String>::new();
    map.insert("Hello".to_owned(), "World".to_owned());
    map
        .iter()
        .find(|(&k, &v)| k == "Hello")
        .unwrap();
}
```

It gives me following error -

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of a shared reference
 --> src/main.rs:8:16
  |
8 |         .find(|(&k, &v)| k == "Hello")
  |                ^^-^^^-^
  |                  |   |
  |                  |   ...and here
  |                  data moved here
  |
  = note: move occurs because these variables have types that don't implement the `Copy` trait
```

My question is why? The closure in `find` takes a `&Self::Item` therefore the iterator item is (&String, &String), which when used with the find function is actually `(&&String, &&String)`. Me using the pattern (&k, &v) should move a string reference into k and v and not the actual string itself. So how am I moving out of a shared reference?

Another possibility is that the iterator item in find is actually `&(&String, &String)`. But that should only happen when I explicitly place that `&` outside the `(&String, &String)`. What is happening when I don't use that outer `&` explicitly?

Comment: basically is what you got there.  But item is `(&String, &String)`, hence in find you get `&(&String, &String)`

Comment: Hi, @Kshitij Jain. Yesterday I reviewed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71732428/14092446), and found something contradictory, which means this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71733238/14092446) written by me maybe is also wrong. If you wanna check it out, follow this [post](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/help-understanding-match-ergonomics/74548). If you wanna contact me, email me, my mail address is available on my stack overflow profile page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71732428/14092446) should answer your question, the magic hidden here is [match ergonomics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2005-match-ergonomics.md).

```rust
(&k, &v) = &(&String, &String)
// k and v are of type `String`
```

Rustc process this matching from outside inwards, the step-by-step procedure is:

First, we are matching `(&k, &v)` against `&(&String, &String)`. In this step, `(&k, &v)` is the non-reference pattern, and the RHS is `&(&String, &String)`, so what rustc does is dereference the RHS and update `bind mode` to `ref`.

Next, we are matching `&k` against `&String`(Also, we are matching `&v` against `&String`, the process is similar). In this step, `&k` is the pattern begining with `&`, which is `reference pattern` according to the [Definitions](https://github.com/SteveLauC/rfcs/blob/add-missing-code-highlight/text/2005-match-ergonomics.md#definitions). Remember match ergonomic is designed for the situation where a reference value is matched by a **non-reference pattern**, so when we are operating on the `reference pattern`, rustc leave all the stuff relevant to this RFC behind. So we get the variable `k` of type `String`

Comment: Thanks for asking the other question @Steve. I think my confusion was stemming from the fact that I did not full understand (even after reading the match ergonomics rfc) what the compiler does while performing pattern matching on tuples. The answer to your question makes it pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

Following your logic that was almost there. The chain of types would be something similar to the example:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let tup: (String, String) = ("Foo".to_string(), "Bar".to_string());
    let item: (&String, &String) = (&tup.0, &tup.1);
    let find_item: &(&String, &String) = &item;
    let (&k, &v) = find_item;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=db96c942726d53103025e5474eaf05c2)

Which reproduces the same issue. Notice the types, you do not have a `&&String`, so when you pattern match it is trying to move them.

Comment: So the behavior here is when you match `(&k, &v) = &(&String, &String)`, `k` and `v` are of the type `String`. I am curious how this matching happens? Is there any official doc elaborating on this issue? Thx!

Comment: @SteveLau, is just how pattern matching works really. In match statements and let bindings.

Answer (score 0):

This is because rust thinks you are attempting to match the `&` in addition to the tuple to get a value which is not a reference. By matching `&x = y` you are acknowledging that `y` is a reference and asking to ignore it when handling `x`. Or in other words, treat `x` as `*y`*. However dereferencing a reference in this manor would require it to implement `Copy`.

```rust
let items: (&i32, &i32) = (&45, &24);

let (a, b) = &items;
let _: &i32 = a;  // Works
let _:  i32 = a;  // Errors (can not be implicitly dereferenced)
let _:  i32 = *a; // Works

let (&a, &b) = &items;
let _: &i32 = a;  // Errors (a is not a reference)
let _:  i32 = a;  // Works
let _:  i32 = *a; // Errors (i32 can not be dereferenced)
```

Or another way you can think about it is that `let (&a, &b) = &items;` is roughly equivalent to this:

```rust
let (a, b) = &items;
let a = *a;
let b = *b;
```

Comment: Seems `let (a, b) = &items; let _: i32 = *a` does not work, here is the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c7e0fbc760d21ab48684f512f1507228). By the way, is there any official doc elaborating on this issue? I feel it is some kind of magic hidden in the compiler, thx!

Comment: `let _:  i32 = *a; // Works`
^ This does not work in the playground. The error is -


```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:9:19
  |
9 |     let _:  i32 = *a; // Works
  |             ---   ^^ expected `i32`, found `&i32`
  |             |
  |             expected due to this
  |
help: consider dereferencing the borrow
  |
9 |     let _:  i32 = **a; // Works
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `&`s:

```rust
        .find(|(k, _v)| *k == "Hello")
```

[Full, compiling code in Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1d2567a64af31f71d97ee4aa21d9f498)

[The answer by Locke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71650953/8037600) explains why your code didn't work.

Note 1: I also dereferenced the k with `*k` to compare it with "Hello" because `k` has type `&&String`, which you can't compare with `&str`. `*k` then has type `&String`, which you can compare with `&str`.
Additionally, I put a `_` before the `v` to silence the unused-variable compiler warning.

Note 2: If you actually wanted to get an extra reference for `k` and `v` (which you don't need), you could have written `.find(|(ref k, ref v)| ...`.