# Weird type when pattern matching references

Tags: rust, types, pattern-matching, type-inference, match-ergonomics

I encountered this strange behaviour when reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71650383/ambiguous-behavior-in-iterator-while-using-the-find-filter-methods), and the core question of this post is **when you matching `(&k, &v) = &(&String, &String)` , `k` and `v` will get the type `String`** .

To figure out what's happending, I wote the following test code, and the result is much more shocking and confusing to me:

> [Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ecc35612b64020901fde3e757f7e3368)

```rust
fn main() {
    let x: &(&String, &String) = &(&String::new(), &String::new());
    let ref_to_x: &&(&String, &String) = &x;
    let ref_ref_to_x: &&&(&String, &String) = &&x;
    let ref_ref_ref_to_x: &&&&(&String, &String) = &&&x;
    
    // code snippet 1
    let (a, b) = x;                // type of a: &&String, type of b: &&String
    let (a, b) = ref_to_x;         // type of a: &&String, type of b: &&String
    let (a, b) = ref_ref_to_x;     // type of a: &&String, type of b: &&String
    let (a, b) = ref_ref_ref_to_x; // type of a: &&String, type of b: &&String

    // code snippet 2
    let &(a, b) = x;                // type of a: &String, type of b: &String
    let &(a, b) = ref_to_x;        // type of a: &&String, type of b: &&String
    let &(a, b) = ref_ref_to_x;    // type of a: &&String, type of b: &&String
    let &(a, b) = ref_ref_ref_to_x;// type of a: &&String, type of b: &&String

    // code snippet 3
    let (&a, &b) = x;               // type of a: String, type of b: String
    let (&a, &b) = ref_to_x;        // type of a: String, type of b: String
    let (&a, &b) = ref_ref_to_x;    // type of a: String, type of b: String
    let (&a, &b) = ref_ref_ref_to_x;// type of a: String, type of b: String
}
```

The type annotation of `a` and `b`  I added to the end of line is inferred by `rust-analyzer`.

Please **NOTE**, `code snippet 3` **won't compile** due to the error `can not move out of xx because it's borrowrd/can not move out of xx which is behind a shared reference`, but I think this doesn't matter (Perhaps I am wrong here, if so, point me out, thanks) cause we are concentrating on the type of `a` and `b`.

My questions are:

1. why do `a` and `b` always have the same type even when the RHS have different types(x/ref_to_x/ref_ref_to_x..) in code snippet 1/2/3?
2. how does this matching happen(a step-by-step matching process would be appreciated) ?
3. How can I get the exactly same type inference as `rust-analyzer/rustc` when writing code?

BTW, is this relevant to the [rfc 2005 match-ergonomics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2005-match-ergonomics.md)? I googled a lot and found many people mentioned this in their answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. What you see is match ergonomics in action, and their behavior may not be what you'd expect.

The way match ergonomics work is by using *binding modes*. There are three binding modes available, and they can be used even without match ergonomics:

- Move. This was the default binding mode before match ergonomics were introduced, and it always tries to move (or copy) the value.
- `ref`. This is what you get when you apply the `ref` operator to a binding (surprisingly), and it adds **one** reference. For example, in `match e { ref r => ... }`, `r` is `&e`.
- `ref mut`. Similar to `ref`, but uses a mutable borrow (and specified using the `ref mut` operator).

The process works as follows: the compiler process the pattern from the outside inwards. The process starts with `move` as the binding mode.

Each time the compiler needs to match a *non-reference pattern* (literal, struct, tuple, slice) against a reference, it automatically dereferences the reference and update the binding mode: when `&` reference is matched against we'll get the `ref` binding mode, and for `&mut` references we will get `ref` if the current binding mode is `ref` or otherwise `ref mut`. Then this process repeats until we don't have a reference anymore.

If we're matching against a *reference pattern* (binding, wildcard, `const`s of reference types or `&`/`&mut` patterns), the default binding mode is reset back to `move`.

When a variable is being bound, the compiler looks at the current binding mode: for `move`, it'll match the type as-is. For `ref` and `ref mut`, it will add `&` or `&mut`, respectively. **But only one**.

Let's follow your examples line-by-line.

```rust
let (a, b) = x;                // type of a: &&String, type of b: &&String
```

We match a *non-reference pattern* (a tuple pattern) against a reference (of type `&(&String, &String)`). So we dereference the reference and set the binding mode to `ref`.

Now we got a tuple pattern to match against a tuple of type `(&String, &String)` and a binding mode of `ref`. We match `a` against `&String`: it's a reference pattern (binding), and so we don't change the binding mode. However, we already have a binding mode of `ref`. The type we match against is `&String`, and `ref` means we add a reference, so we end with `&&String`. Exactly the same thing happens to `b`.

```rust
let (a, b) = ref_to_x;         // type of a: &&String, type of b: &&String
```

Here, just like in the previous example, we match a non-reference pattern (a tuple pattern) against a reference (`&&(&String, &String)`). So we dereference and set the binding mode to `ref`. But we still have a reference: `&(&String, &String)`. So we dereference again. The binding mode is already `ref`, so we don't need to touch it. We end with matching `(a, b)` against `(&String, &String)`. This means `a = &String`, `b = &String`. But remember we're using the `ref` binding mode, so we should add a reference. We add **only one** reference, **even though we matched against two!** At the end, we have `a = &&String`, `b = &&String`.

The remaining examples in this code snippet work the same way.

```rust
let &(a, b) = ref_to_x;        // type of a: &&String, type of b: &&String
```

Here, we first match the `&` pattern against the reference of type `&&(&String, &String)`. This removes both references, causing us to match `(a, b)` against `&(&String, &String)`. From now on we continue just like in the first example.

The remaining examples in this snippet are similar.

```rust
let (&a, &b) = x;               // type of a: String, type of b: String
```

This is the most interesting one. Remember how we talked about reference vs. non-reference patterns? In this example that fact plays a cruical role.

First we match the tuple pattern against the type `&(&String, &String)`. We dereference the tuple and set `binding_mode = ref`. Now we match the tuple: we got to match `&a` and `&b` each against `&String`, with the binding mode set to `ref`.

What happens when we match `&a` against `&String`? Well, remember `&` is a reference pattern, and when matching reference patterns we **completely ignore the binding mode**. So we match `&a` against `&String`, with the binding mode reset to `move`. This removes the reference from both sides, leaving us with `a = String`. Same for `&b`.

The next examples in this code snippet are the same.

Comment: "If we're matching against a reference pattern (binding, wildcard, `consts` of reference types or `&`/`&mut` patterns), the default binding mode is reset back to `move`." The match ergonomics RFC states "The default binding mode only changes when matching a reference with a non-reference pattern." So while this appears to be what's happening, it's contradicts the explicit wording in the RFC.

Comment: @SvenMarnach True, but [later PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/48448) changed that (although I'm still not entirely sure what I wrote is completely correct, need to double-check when I'm less tired).

Comment: I think your answer correctly describes the compiler behaviour. The documentation seems to be wrong, or at the very least incomplete.

Comment: @SvenMarnach It was the behavior when the RFC was accepted, but has changed since. Still, I'm not sure my description is accurate, it may be just `&` patterns and not any refernce pattern.

Comment: The Rust reference has similar wording, though it does not include the exact sentence I quoted above. I'll file a bug if I still remember it after work today.

Answer (score 0):

This is called "destructuring". It's used commonly in pattern matching like with `if let Some(val) = option`.

Essentially, this:

```rust
let x: (&String, &String) = (&String::new(), &String::new());
let (&a, &b) = x; // a: String, b: String
```

Is equivalent to this:

```rust
let (&a, &b) = (&String::new(), &String::new()); // a: String, b: String
```

Which is equivalent to this:

```rust
let (a, b) = (String::new(), String::new());
```

To explain more, I'll use a simpler example.

```rust
let value: String = String::new();
let &also_value = &value; // also_value: String
```

Destructuring works kind of by "simplifying" both sides. In this case, it will dereference both sides, resulting in

```rust
let also_value = value;
```

This also works through indirection. If we add a step in between:

```rust
let value: String = String::new();
let ref_to_value: &String = &value;
let &also_value = ref_to_value; // also_value: String
```

It can see through the indirection, and will now dereference `ref_to_value` to get `String` again.

Match ergonomics may also be involved, but only for dereferencing the whole tuple.

Note: to get a reference in destructuring assignment, you can instead use `ref`:

```rust
let value: String = String::new();
let ref ref_to_value = value; // ref_to_value: &String
```

Generally this is only used in pattern matching like:

```rust
if let Some(ref x) = option { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it seems that this answer doesn't answer my question, the example you gave is quite straightforward. What baffled me is why `a` and `b` have same type in code snippet 1/2/3 even when the RHS has different types(I will update my question to make it clearer, sorry about this)